# insufficient system memory in resource pool

Tags: sql, ssis

I run my SSIS project and I got error.

> There is insufficient system memory in resource pool

How to check memory resource pool and know which query/project to spend mymmemory

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Increase server memory (sql server property >Memory >Maximum server memory .)

kill use less process(sql).

Close unwanted process from task manager too.

[Good link](http://sqlserverlearner.com/2011/there-is-insufficient-system-memory-in-resource-pool-default-to-run-this-query)